# Detecting active AVAudioSessions on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiosession

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible - my app activates an audio session that is initialized as:

```
[[[AVAudioSession alloc] init] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
```

I would like to be able to understand when an additional audio session that originated from another app or the OS is playing.

I know about the ability to implement the delegate methods `beginInterruption:` and `endInterruption` but these won't get invoked because of the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` option I'm using.

Is there a way to achieve this without using private API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The way you manage your application's Audio Session has had some significant changes since **iOS 6.0**, and deserves a brief mention first. Before **iOS 6.0** you would make use of **AVAudioSession** and **AudioSessionServices** classes, incorporating delegation and property listening respectively. From **iOS 6.0** onwards use **AVAudioSession** class and incorporate notifications.

The following is for *iOS 6.0* onwards.

To tell if other audio outside your applications sandbox is playing use -

```
// query if other audio is playing
BOOL isPlayingWithOthers = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
// test it with...
(isPlayingWithOthers) ? NSLog(@"other audio is playing") : NSLog(@"no other audio is playing");
```

As for interruption handling you'll need to observe `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` and `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`. So in the class that manages your audio session you could put something like the following - this should be called once at the start of the application lifecycle and don't forget to remove observer in the dealloc method of the same class.

```
// ensure we already have a singleton object
    [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    // register for notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(interruption:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(routeChange:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And finally add the following selectors `interruption:` and `routeChange:` - these will receive a `NSNotification` object that has a property called userInfo of type `NSDictionary` that you read to assist any conditionals your application has.

```
- (void)interruption:(NSNotification*)notification {
// get the user info dictionary
NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;
// get the AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey enum from the dictionary
NSInteger interuptionType = [[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] integerValue];
// decide what to do based on interruption type here...
switch (interuptionType) {
    case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:
        NSLog(@"Audio Session Interruption case started.");
        // fork to handling method here...
        // EG:[self handleInterruptionStarted];
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:
        NSLog(@"Audio Session Interruption case ended.");
        // fork to handling method here...
        // EG:[self handleInterruptionEnded];
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"Audio Session Interruption Notification case default.");
        break;
} }
```

And similarly...

```
- (void)routeChange:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;

NSInteger routeChangeReason = [[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];

switch (routeChangeReason) {
    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonUnknown:
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonUnknown");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable:
        // a headset was added or removed
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable:
        // a headset was added or removed
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange:
        // called at start - also when other audio wants to play
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange");//AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOverride:
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOverride");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonWakeFromSleep:
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonWakeFromSleep");
        break;

    case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNoSuitableRouteForCategory:
        NSLog(@"routeChangeReason : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNoSuitableRouteForCategory");
        break;

    default:
        break;
} }
```

There is no need to poll anything as long as you check the state of your applications audio session say for example in the `viewDidLoad` of your root view controller, at the start of you apps lifecycle. Any changes from there onwards to your applications audio session will be known via these two main notifications. Replace the `NSLog` statements with what ever your code needs to do based on the cases contained in the switch.

You can find more information about `AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey` and  `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey` in the `AVAudioSession` class reference documentation.

My apologies for the long answer but I think Audio Session management in iOS is rather fiddly and Apple's Audio Session Programming Guide, at the time of writing this, does not include code examples using notifications for interruption handling.

Comment: Thanks for a very insightful and detailed answer. I've tried registering for these notifications, then playing music via an external app (for instance settings->ringtones) but they never get called. Any ideas?

Comment: The notifications are posted on the main thread. To confirm this try building to a device then background your application. Then open the music app and start playing an audio track. Now bring your app back to the foreground and you should receive a route change notification. Audio session behaviour is dependant on not just your audio session but on all involved and their current state. I use the music app to test with because I know that it's audio session allows it to play with others whereas I'm not sure if the settings app allows it to behave the same. Also don't test this in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this and report back with findings

Comment: Note that the recently updated AurioTouch(not AurioTouch2) now includes a lot of the above code. Also be aware that as of iOS 7 it is now possible to write InterApp audio.

Comment: Will the route change or interruption be triggered if user enters a phone call or disconnects the call. I want to be able to detect if microphone is available for recording a video, and if the user is on a phone call microphone isn't available. What is the best way to detect microphone availability taking into account phone calls.

Comment: Is it required to Activate your Session again after an interruption? For instance, when the interruption is over, should there be code in that notification handler to `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&theError]`

Answer (score 5):

You can check if other audio is playing like this:

```
UInt32 otherAudioIsPlaying;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof (otherAudioIsPlaying);
AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &propertySize, &otherAudioIsPlaying );

[self handleIfAudioIsPlaying: otherAudioIsPlaying];
```

Then you can add a loop and check every X second if something changed.

Comment: Thanks, though I want to refrain from a "polling" approach. I'd like to get notified when this happens.

Comment: Maybe this could help: AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, callBack, (__bridge void *)(self));

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll try it out

Comment: AudioSessionAddPropertyListener is deprecated. Any alternative?

Comment: Also, the callback isn't being invoked when I play audio on the device.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. Maybe it not possible without private API, and you have to go with the ugly polling method I posted below, and file a request to Apple for the feature.