# How to know if FaceTime is already in use

Tags: ios, iphone, url, openurl, facetime

I start a FaceTime call from my app using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"facetime://" stringByAppendingString:appleID]]]
```

Is there a way to know if FaceTime is already in use or the URL is already open when i call this method?

Or is it possible to know when i come back into my app after opening the URL?

Comment: What does `canOpenURL:` return?

Comment: Hi, canOpenURL: returns true even when FaceTime is already in use. 
My wish is to check if I am already calling with FaceTime.
I guess that canOpenURL: check only if FaceTime is available in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did to know if FaceTime was already in use/busy on another call is to check if other audio is playing on my device, taking the idea from this other question:
[Detecting active AVAudioSessions on iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371388/detecting-active-avaudiosessions-on-ios-device).

```
// check if other audio is playing
BOOL isPlayingWithOthers = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];

if(isPlayingWithOthers){
    NSLog(@"other audio is playing - FaceTime could be in use");
    //do nothing
}else{
    NSLog(@"no other audio is playing - FaceTime not in use");
}
```

I guess this does not ensure that it is FaceTime playing audio outside my app but it works fine for the goal i had to achieve.